# Scala String trimming by a set of characters

Tags: string, scala

Given any set of (trailing) characters, for instance

```
val s = "un".toSet
```

how to trim a string by `s`, namely,

```
"untidy stringnu".trimBy(s)
res: String = tidy string
```

Comment: I guess I rushed into answering. How do you specify that a prefix or suffix should be trimmed based on the set of chars? Any char from the set? all chars from the set? From the example, looks like order does not matter. e.g. How do you determine that in the above example, "stringnu".trimBy(s) is "string" and not "stri"

Comment: @maasg any element in the set any number of times regardless of order, yet only in the beginning or ending of the string, namely trailiing characters set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala has a `dropWhile` that solves half of the problem. It also has a `dropRight` that's an analog to `drop` for the right end of the collection. Unfortunately it doesn't have a `dropWhileRight`, though, so you have to get creative.

If you don't particularly care about efficiency, you can just drop the characters off the left end, reverse, repeat, and reverse again:

```
scala> "untidy stringnu".dropWhile(s).reverse.dropWhile(s).reverse
res0: String = tidy string
```

If you're sure that's going to be a bottleneck in your program (hint: it's probably not), you'll want some kind of imperative solution.

Answer (score 3):

The triple quotes are reflexive. As in pure reflex.

```
scala> val s = "undo"
s: String = undo

scala> val r = s"""[$s]*(.*?)[$s]*""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = [undo]*(.*?)[undo]*

scala> def f(x: String) = x match { case r(y) => y case z => z }
f: (x: String)String

scala> f("nodu some string here...donuts are goodun")
res0: String = " some string here...donuts are g"

scala> f("undoundo")
res1: String = ""
```

or

```
scala> val r = s"""[$s]*(?:(.*[^$s])[$s]*|$$)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = [undo]*(?:(.*[^undo])[undo]*|$)

scala> def f(x: String) = x match { case r(null) => "" case r(y) => y case z => z }
f: (x: String)String
```

Comment: Some escaping required on the string.